# High errors in transmission (completely eliminated by adding delay): What's the issue?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, xbee

I am using a two Arduino setup with two XBee radios. One radio is sending data and the other is receiving data. I am sending three sensor readings following a protocol which uses three bytes for each sensor reading. Byte one is sensor information, byte two is data, and byte three is for error checking. When I run the set up for about 5 minutes I get approximately 47% errors in transmission. Once one error occurs, there seems to be an avalanche of errors. However, when I add delay in between sending bytes (100ms between bytes and 1s between sensor) it works perfectly. I've tried expanding the hardware buffer, but this didn't work.

```
        delay(2000);

        // Calcuate weather parameters for serial and web
        calcWeather(); // Go calc all the various sensors

        // send weather out to serial port
        if (prevtemplm34_1 == templm34_1) // 2 in a row must be the same to send
        {
            Serial.write(0);
            Serial.write(templm34_1);
            Serial.write(templm34_1 ^ 0);
        }

        // send weather out to serial port
        if(prevtemplm34_2 == templm34_2) // 2 in a row must be the same to send
        { 
            Serial.write(1);
            Serial.write(templm34_2);
            Serial.write(templm34_2 ^ 1);
        }

        // send weather out to serial port
        if(prevtemplm34_3 == templm34_3) // 2 in a row must be the same to send
        {
            Serial.write(2);
            Serial.write(templm34_3);
            Serial.write(templm34_3 ^ 2);
        }
        delay(2000);
```

The code for parsing received data is:

```
int readData ()
{ 
// There must be at least three available bytes to satisfy the protocol
// Otherwise, wait until three bytes have arrived to read anything
if (Serial.available() >= 3) {

      // Read the next three byte in the serial buffer
      incomingByteOne = Serial.read();
      Serial.write("Byte One: ");
      Serial.write(incomingByteOne);
      Serial.println();
      incomingByteTwo = Serial.read();
      Serial.write("Byte Two: ");
      Serial.write(incomingByteTwo);
      Serial.println();
      incomingByteThree = Serial.read();
      Serial.write("Byte Three: ");
      Serial.write(incomingByteThree);
      Serial.println();

      // XOR the first and second incoming bytes so that the result can be checked against the third error checking byte
      byte xorValue = incomingByteOne ^ incomingByteTwo;
      Serial.write("XOR VALUE: ");
      Serial.write(xorValue);
      Serial.println("Number of Errors: ");
      Serial.println(numberOfErrors);
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println();
      if(xorValue != incomingByteThree) {
        numberOfErrors++; // Add one to the total count of number of errors in transmission
      } 
      else {
        // Mask for retrieving the five rightmost bits from incomingByteOne (00011111)
        byte maskForSensorNumber = 0x1f;

        // Shift incomingByteOne right 5 times in order to obtain the three bits representing the unit number
        int unitNumber = incomingByteOne >> 5;

        // AND incomingByteOne with the mask in order to retrieve only the five righmost bits representing the sensor number
        int sensorNumber = incomingByteOne & maskForSensorNumber;

        // Store the data for the correct sensor on the correct unit
        data[unitNumber][sensorNumber] = incomingByteTwo*1;
     }
}
}
```

What could be causing the transmissions to work fine with delay, but not otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just transmitting too fast.

Your receiver is writing at least 80 bytes of debugging information (if
I counted it right) for every 3 bytes of incoming data. Since both input
and debug output happen at the same baud rate, this means the receiver
can only cope with an input data rate equal to 3/80 = 3.75% of
the nominal baud rate.

I would expect no errors at the very beginning of the program run,
because the debugging info is written to a RAM buffer. Only when that
buffer fills up the receiver is slowed down by every `Serial.write()`
and `Serial.println()` it performs.

Comment: Thanks @EdgarBonet. When I expanded the receiving and transmitting buffers of the receiver unit to 1,024 bytes, I still had errors after just 7 or so transmissions (just under 600 bytes including debugging). Do you think adding delay is probably one of the better ways to fix this?

Comment: @tpm900: Yes, or maybe show less debugging info.

Comment: I actually only added the debugging after I saw issues with the transmissions. However, I do have approximately 100 writes to a Client (e.g. `client.println("...")`. Does this also affect the buffer?

Comment: I do not know what your client looks like, but it is likely that the `println()` can block.